# mongoDB find a query that throws alert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So I am getting an alert from Mongo - occasionally...

> Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000

Is there a way to see the offending query specifically? I see graphs of trends over time in my dashboard - my "performance advisor" shows no "slow" queries...and the emails alert I get specifically says to check "performance advisor".

Any help

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when the Scanned Object / Returned ratio is large, that means that those queries will be slow and will show up in the slow_query log. If nothing is showing up there, you can reduce the [`slowms` setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel) that determines which queries will be written to the slow query log.

[$explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/#metaOp._S_explain) and the  [$collStats aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/#pipe._S_collStats) are two other tools that are worth being aware of, but for this case I'd recommend updating your [profiling level](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) (`db.setProfilingLevel`) and then seeing where you're at!

If you're using Atlas, the "Profiler" tab shows the queries from the slow query log in an explorable way. If you're not on atlas, [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) has some good mongo log parsing tools.

Comment: is there a place to adjust that setting in the atlas dashboard? or do I need to run that cmd

Comment: I'm unsure; I don't use atlas.

Comment: You can use `db.getProfilingLevel()` to check your profiling level. `db.setProfilingLevel()` can be used to update the values. But it is not advised to change the timings instead of fixing the slow query.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: Main, advice here is to _reduce_ the timings on the slow-query log so that these slow queries actually show up. Definitely don't want to increase the timing there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just recently we have been seeing same error in alerts for our mongo cluster

```
Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000
```

I was not able to find anything that returns this sort of huge chunk in code\logs.

It turned out to be related to our `Charts` page, ie it is firing when we open charts.
*I suppose because of the lot's of aggregations it does, and I am not sure how to optimise those, as it's mainly UI set up*

So if you have any charts on mongodb, it worth check if opening those triggers the alert.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).